# Test void method that prints with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a class that only contains a main method which has some System.out.println calls which I need to test.  I agree that the design of this class is not great, but I have to leave it as is.  I am not sure in Mockito how to test the proper values are being printed.  I have seen similar questions answered on StackOverflow, but they are different because the calls to System.out.println is actually in the test and not in the class being tested.

```
public final class ConnectionPasswordEncryptor {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    final String usage = "Generate encrypted password using PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm, "
            + "only one argument is accepted, and it can't be empty.";

    if (arg.length == 1) {
        String pwd = StringUtils.trimToNull(arg[0]);
        if (pwd == null) {
            print(usage);
            return;
        }

        print(PasswordEncryptionUtil.encrypt(pwd));

    }
    else if ((arg.length == 2) && ("-d".equalsIgnoreCase(arg[0]))) {
        print(PasswordEncryptionUtil.decrypt(arg[1]));
    }
    else {
        print(usage);
    }
}

private static void print(final String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}

private ConnectionPasswordEncryptor() {
    // prevent from initialization
}

}
```

For instance, one test I want to do is to test that the proper message is printed if invalid arguments are sent:
            String[] arg = new String[] {"xx", "abcd1234"};
            ConnectionPasswordEncryptor.main(arg);
The call does not return anything, but prints to standard out.  How do I retrieve what was printed to standard out?

Comment: You can also introduce a `PrintWriter`

Comment: I saw that one, but it seemed to be different than mine.  I will read through again and see if I can make it apply.

Comment: OK, I was able to get it to work using the suggestion for capturing the PrintStream using System.setOut.